# xslt file not able to find in classpath

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xslt, apache-camel

trying to transform one xml to another xml using XSLT file which contains rule

reading from input folder transforimng with **xslt present in src/main/resources/test.xslt** and output storing in output folder in F drive

```
 @Component
  public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:F:\\input")
        .to("xslt:file:///springApp/test.xslt")
        .to("file:F:\\output");
        
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xml.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>springApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Error:-

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:122) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:270) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:157) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]


Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\springApp\test.xslt (The network path was not found)
    at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeException(RuntimeCamelException.java:66) ~[camel-api-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.doFail(BaseService.java:409) ~[camel-api-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
```

Tried changing the path -

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:F:\\input")
        .to("xslt:springApp/src/main/resources/test.xslt")
        .to("file:C:\\output");
```

}

Getting error

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[xslt:springApp/src/main/resources/test.xslt] <<< in route: Route(route1)[From[file:F:\input] -> [To[xslt:springApp because of Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://springApp/src/main/resources/test.xslt due to: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find resource: classpath:springApp /src/main/resources/test.xslt in classpath for URI: classpath:springApp /src/main/resources/test.xslt
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:229) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]

Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://springApp/src/main/resources/test.xslt due to: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find resource: classpath:springApp/src/main/resources/test.xslt in classpath for URI: classpath:springApp/src/main/resources/test.xslt

        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:73) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the relative path from the classpath and this will be:

```
to("xslt:test.xslt")
```